# ForeignObject with Contenteditable in d3 not working with chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I have used a foreignObject attribute to include contenteditable for D3 state Diagram,which was same as Improved state diagram in d3 with slight modification...the problem is that,it is not working  with chrome.

But when I disable .Call(drag) in my code, it is working fine..

Kindly please advice me to fix the issue or an alternate solution..

```
gState.append("foreignObject")
       .attr({ width: 100, height: 100 })
       .attr("x", 35)
       .attr("y",-7)
       .append("xhtml:body")
       .append("xhtml:span")
       .attr("contenteditable", true)
       .html(function (d) { return d.label; })
       .on("click", function (d, i) {
           console.log(d3.select(this).text());
       });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to check the event target inside the drag listener and stop propagation of the drag event if the target is the foreign object or it's children.

**Sample Code:**

```
.on("drag",function(d){
    //Suppose the node group has a circle and g element other than the foreign object.
    if(d3.event.target.tagName!='circle' && d3.event.target.tagName!='g'){ 
         d3.event.stopPropagation();
    } else{
        //drag action
        d.px += d3.event.dx;
        d.py += d3.event.dy;
        d.x += d3.event.dx;
        d.y += d3.event.dy; 
        tick();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Gilsha...if you don't mind can you please  tell me what should I add inside else part.. a little Briefly as I am new to D3

Comment: @Gilsha: I'm getting `d3.event.stopPropagation is not a function`. Plus, if try to log `d3.event.target.tagName`, it is also `undefined`. can you help, please?

Comment: Which version of d3 are you using? @SyedAliTaqi

Comment: @Gilsha do you have a d3v4 solution?